# Apply Color Animation Effects to Grouped Objects in Powerpoint 2010

Tags: colors, microsoft-powerpoint, microsoft-powerpoint-2010, animation

I have about 600 objects on a powerpoint slide, which I want to animate in 6 different stages.

Since I want to have them animated in 6 separate stages, I have them in 6 groups.

When I have them in groups, I cannot select color animation options:

[image: Greyed Out Coloring Icons]

If I ungroup the objects, I can animate them no problem, but then I have 600 items overlapping, and it is a nightmare to try to cope with them afterwards.

Is there any way to apply color animation effects to a group of objects without ungrouping them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The workaround I ended up using was to take the many different shapes, [merge them together](http://blogs.office.com/b/microsoft-powerpoint/archive/2010/02/01/creating-custom-shapes-in-powerpoint-2010.aspx) to create a single custom shape, and then I was able to animate the entire group with color effects.

The only drawback is that if you have overlapping shapes with transparency that you are using to indicate something, merging the shapes will eliminate that effect.

Comment: If combining the shapes works in this case but transparency is an issue, you could instead select the shapes, copy them to the clipboard, then Paste Special, as PNG.  That'd retain transparency.

Answer (score 1):

I have a free PowerPoint add-in that might help.  It's called Selection Manager.

http://www.pptools.com/FAQ00135.htm

The basic idea is that you can select any set of shapes (for instance, choose your group, ungroup it and while all of the shapes in the group are selected, use selection manager to give the selection a name).

At any later time, you can have Selection Manager re-select that same set of shapes with just a click or two.

Comment: Hey Steve, thanks for the link. I am very familiar with your tools and love them to death, but unfortunately the goal is to have someone else maintain and update the presentation, which makes tools troublesome (for a variety of issues). I use them personally though!

Comment: Ah, well.  Too bad.  The reason for it is sort of odd; under the hood, PPT sees a group as a completely new shape, with properties of its own.  What you apply to the group, applies only TO the group, not to any of its child shapes.  When you ungroup, the group shape simply disappears, along with any assigned properties.  This probably should have been done differently, but it's part of the very roots of the app, so there's no way MS could change it.

Comment: yeah, I tried doing all sorts of things like seeing if a group of items, when regrouped, keeps its custom name (no). I did find a solution though, and I will post it myself.